# LoginStatus logout not firing javascript in one specific page of a masterpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net masterpage with a LoginView and LoginStatus control:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                                <LoggedInTemplate>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutText="Log out" OnLoggingOut="LoginStatus1_LoggingOut"
                                        LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" LogoutAction="Redirect" ForeColor="GrayText" />
                                </LoggedInTemplate>
                            </asp:LoginView>
```

Then I have a bunch of regular pages that all uses this master page (through another one). Problem is that in one of them, the logout is not working in IE. The source of the link is the same with below href:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$LoginStatus1$ctl00','')
```

I cannot see any errors in the console and it is working fine in chrome. Also if I run above directly from the IE-js console then it triggers the log out. How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 1):

CausesValidation="false"

Add the above attribute to LinkButton in LoginView, Will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you - that was also the solution I ended up with.